# Using a variable value as a path in a PlaySound

Tags: c++, path

I know how to play a sound I chose: 
`PlaySound(TEXT("Data\\sounds\\Welcome.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);`

The problem is that this other sound, the path is not known because it depends on the result of a variable.

I try to put this value as a path but I can't. Any ideas?

My attempts :
(Admits that ObjectOpe.getCurrentOperateur() returns a string)

```
std::string NameOP = ObjectOpe.getCurrentOperateur();
std::string Path = "Data\\sounds\\Persos\\ATK\\" + NameOP + ".wav";
const char * LPCTSTRPath = Path.c_str();
PlaySound((LPCTSTR)LPCTSTRPath, NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

OR

```
PlaySound(TEXT("Data\\sounds\Persos\\ATK\\" + NameOP + ".wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME)
```

Nothing works.

Thanks to you;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlaySound()` is a preprocessor macro that maps to calling either `PlaySoundA()` or `PlaySoundW()` depending on whether your project is configured to map `TCHAR` to `char` or `wchar_t`.

For what you are attempting, just get rid of your typecast and call `PlaySoundA()` directly:

```
std::string NameOP = ObjectOpe.getCurrentOperateur();
std::string Path = "Data\\sounds\\Persos\\ATK\\" + NameOP + ".wav";
PlaySoundA(Path.c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

Or:

```
PlaySoundA(("Data\\sounds\Persos\\ATK\\" + NameOP + ".wav").c_str(), NULL, SND_FILENAME)
```